# dynamic Progress bar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Progress Bar:

```
state = {
  progress: 0,
}

  render() {

    return (
       <Progress value={this.state.progress} title="Saving the details"/>

    );
```

This is my progress bar, i want this progress bar to increase dynamically with the interval of time. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
componentDidMount() {
    let counter = 1;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
        this.setState({
            progress : counter
        })
        if(counter == 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

---

You can run the below code snippet and review :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    progress : 0
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let counter = 1;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
        this.setState({
            progress : counter
        })
        if(counter == 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Progress : { this.state.progress }
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's right. just use this code:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({progress: prevState.progress + 10}))
}, 5000)
```

you can write this every where you want. like `componentDidMount` or in a custom function.

Comment: it is throwing an error in progress, saying any
Property 'progress' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.